# R: GAM with multiple negative binomial thetas

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I fit a Generalized Additive Model in the Negative Binomial family using `gam` from the `mgcv` package. I have a data frame containing my dependent variable `Y`, an independent variable `X`, other independent variables `Oth` and a factor `Fac`. I would like to fit the following model

`Y ~ s(X) + Oth`

with a different `theta` per factor level. In other words, I use

`fit <- gam(Y~s(X)+Oth, family=nb())`

but this only gives me one dispersion parameter `theta` for the whole dataset. Instead, I believe that the mean is the same across factors, hence only one set of coefficients are required for `s(X)` and `Oth`, but the variance changes across factors, so I would like one dispersion estimate `theta` per level of `Fac`.

Naturally, fitting one model per factor level does not work because I would then get one set of coefficients for the independent variables per factor level, instead of one for the whole dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve your problem is to use a `gamlss` package. You will be able to model `mean` by `X` variables and `variance` by `X` and `Fac` variables so you will get parameters for all `levels` of your factor.